# Copy Eventlistener doesn't fire in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, event-listener

I have a `copy` eventlistener set up for a `div`. It works in Chrome but not in Firefox. I've tried setting `oncopy` instead, but without any success. Google search doesn't bring up any mention of this. Any ideas what is the problem and how to fix?

As an example, the below snippet will show "copied div" with `CTRL-C` (or right click + copy) in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Thanks for your help.

```js
var div = document.getElementById('divid');

div.addEventListener("copy", () => {console.log("copied div")} );

div.onclick = () => {console.log("clicked on div")}
```

```css
#divid {
width: 100px;
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id='divid'>Content of div</div>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug with Firefox 110.0. To check if your version of Firefox supports the copy event (it's highly unlikely it doesn't, since it's supported from FFv22 onwards), have you checked the docs page? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event

Comment: Strange, I am using version 110.0 as well. So, you CTRL-C and get "copied div"? What would cause your install to work and mine not? I am using Windows 11. I've also disabled Ghostery.

Comment: Either disable all extensions on your browser or try it in in cognito mode. You might have a browser plugin that is interfering with copy events.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I disabled all extensions and ran in a private window and still no luck.

Comment: OK, I've tried another PC and indeed it works. Thanks for the time to try it out and report back. I at least have a clue now.

Comment: @Terry - I found the problem was a modified `about:config` setting. `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` was set to disabled. No idea how, but all is good now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the following Firefox setting got changed / disabled, but I had the inspiration to search within `about:config` for "clipboard".

I found a setting for `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` and it was set to `false`. Toggling the value to `true` solved the issue.